# How can I synchronize the shell view and Finder view of a directory?

Tags: finder, command-line

Using the shell, I opened a tar file that was full of db dumps that were compressed with bzip2. For each dump file, I (1) unzipped, (2) loaded, (3) deleted.

From the shell, the directory where I worked looks perfect. Using *Finder*, the directory view has frozen on what the directory looked like immediately after I untarred. None of the changes caused by `~/WorkArea/bzip2 -d *dmp.bz2` or `~/WorkArea/rm *dmp` are reflected. Also, mysteriously a directory titled `Disk1` is now viewable in *Finder*. That directory was never viewable in the shell.

Trying to move or delete any file with *Finder* in that directory gives a
`The operation can't be completed because an unexpected error occurred (error code -1407)`.

How can *Finder* get synchronized with the work I did in the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known quirk with Finder; it's supposed to refresh automatically, but sometime it's won't.  Unlike Windows, there is no refresh button nor can you press F5 to refresh the window.

There are more details and workarounds to this in the article [Refreshing Finder Windows in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2013/08/30/refreshing-finder-windows-in-mac-os-x/).  However, I find that the easiest thing is to just go up one directory and then back.

If you use [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), you could create a "refresh keystroke" of sorts by mapping a key combo to something like <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>  and then <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> which will take to you the Applications Folder then back to where you were.

Comment: Going up / down in Finder created 3 more "Disk1" directories. "Disk1" is disk that has OSx installed on.  All 3 are empty, and I don't see them in the shell. I'm too nervous about what is happening to my file system, so I'm just going to reboot.

Comment: The re-boot fixed the Finder view. Thanks for the info and I'll use it to keep a closer eye on my shell work. But, if my boot volume gets mixed-up in the problem I'm gonna re-boot.